# Es posible tener dos ion-Content cada uno en ocupando la mitad de pantalla, independientes entre si?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

```
<ion-pane ng-controller="exampleGCtrl">
    <ion-content class="has has-header has-footer" scroll="false">
        <div id="MyMap" class="map" scroll="false"></div>
        <div ng-click="centerOnMe();" class="button button-icon ion-android-locate botonFind"></div>
        <div class="absolute button button-outline:color ion-navicon button-dark"></div>
        <ion-scroll class="listContainer">
                <ion-list class="lista">
                    <ion-radio ng-repeat="lugares in array_marcadores" ng-click="setMarcadores(lugares.posLat,lugares.posLng)">{{lugares.nombre}}</ion-radio>
                </ion-list>
        </ion-scroll>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo Solucione, solo que me dejo un detalle en la parte superior de la lista de marcadores. Un espacio que su propiedad viene del `ion-content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede, por que no usas un solo ion-content con dos divs, y al segundo de habilitas el scroll con overflow:scroll.

```html
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <div id="MyMap" class="map"></div>
  <div class="absolute button button-outline:color ion-navicon button-dark"></div>
  <div style="overflow:scroll">
    <div class="lista">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-repeat="lugares in array_marcadores" ng-click="setMarcadores(lugares.posLat,lugares.posLng)">{{lugares.nombre}}</ion-radio>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Si necesitas que ocupe la mitad de la pantalla le pones height en 50%

Comment: realice todo lo que sugeriste pero me surgio un problema, edite la pregunta

Comment: no me habilita el scroll de la lista

Comment: Le pusiste el overflow: scroll;
??? Al sobrepasar la capacidad del div deberia habilitar el scroll

Comment: le añadi, lo que me sugeriste, pero esta estatico..